# Hardware Write Blocked SD Reader

Tags: forensics

I needed to look into getting a hardware write blocker that will be compatible with SD cards.  I've come across the [Tableau Forensic USB 3.0 Bridge](https://www.guidancesoftware.com/tableau/hardware/t8u)  and the [CRU USB 3.0 WriteBlocker](https://www.cru-inc.com/products/wiebetech/usb-3-0-writeblocker/)

Does anyone have experience in either of these hooking a SD reader (card from a camera) up to it?  Or something else - it has to be a separate hardware write-block device.  Preferably without the ability to optionally write back.